# windows 8 no networks found-broadcom

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, drivers

I have a problem with my wireless device. I am using windows 8, it says "no networks found" even if there are 10-15 networks nearby. It was working properly like 2-3 months ago ( so it was working on windows 8).

I tried installing windows 8 drivers, windows 7 drivers, all of them but none of them worked. I fear that it is an hardware problem, not a driver problem.

My computer is HP Pavilion dv6-6030et. And my wireless network adapter is Broadcom 4313. I can post troubleshooting report if you need it.

Comment: To see if it is a hardware problem you can try your wifi in another operating system. You could install Ubuntu and dual boot.  You also know if the network is correctly configured on the modem/router end when you can connect okay via Ethernet.

Comment: The problem might be a firewall or antivirus program, have you installed such software on your PC ? Also you might have turned on IPV6, check that out too.

Comment: I checked firewall before, but i will try that again. I didn't check IPv6 and don't have any idea how to turn it or off, can you give me more details?

Comment: Open Network and Sharing from the Control Panel. Select "Change adapter settings" on the left sidebar. Then, right click the network device you want to disable IP6 on and select "Properties". Scroll through the list of items to find "Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCIP/IPv6)" and uncheck it. Click OK and it will be disabled on that connections.Windows will disconnect from the network for a few seconds after you hit OK. Check if this solves your problem, if not turn IPV6 again on.

Comment: It is not related with ipv6 or windows firewall. Still can't find any connections to connect. Should I try it with windows8 drivers too? I removed and installed drivers like thousand times so do you think that would corrupt configuration settings of wifi?

Comment: Go to the site of your network wireless adapter and download from there the driver. Make sure that it is the correct one. Try also to boot in safe mode with network enabled and see if you can connect. If it does not help then you have too check from another Operating System if it can detect a Wireless Connection to make sure that it is not a hardware problem.

Comment: Btw, refreshing my notebook solved the question. I would suggest anyone experiencing this problem to do the same.